# Device Name and Browser Details in Magento

Tags: php, magento

How we can get the Device Name in Magento.

I will be getting Browser Details using user agent:

```
Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpUserAgent();
```

I have tried by not Getting device name like `Mobile/Tablet` and `Desktop` etc.

Also it is possible to get Name of Device like `Google Nexus`, `Blackberry`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) contains an information about browser and device which being used. You can use it to evaluate what browser and device being used for example

```
if(stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPod")!=false ){
        // iPhone/iPod
}else if(stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPad")!=false){
        // iPhone/iPad
}else ifstripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Android")!=false){
        // Android device
}...
```

Or you may check PHP [Mobile-Detect](https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect/) class to detect mobile devices